# Pulling Youtube Live Cast CHAT into c#

Tags: c#, youtube, chat, live

I learn best through examples.

Could someone please help me with a quick and dirty example of how to pull LIVE chat from a youtube LIVE stream? (I need to be able to pull out people's questions/comments for analysis later.) I HAVE looked through the partial examples listed but I'm a bit lost with how to implement them.

Basically, what I need is to be able to pull the live video chat into a C# in the following format:

Chat Name --- Comment

I tried just creating a browser element so that I could then scrape the data, but it doesn't seem to be pulling anything.

If you can provide an example for me, THANK YOU. If you want to point me to a solution that has this somewhere GREAT! (I wasn't able to find any after 10+ hours of searching.

Thank you for any help offered.